# I have data in byte array that uses UTF8 encoding and is represented by values from 0 to 255. ow to convert that data in the original form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, epplus

[Here is the byte data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXz4a.png)I tried using .ConverttoBase64 and ASCII. Following is a piece of code:

```
response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
string s = response.ContentEncoding.GetString(fileBytes);`
```

The data is coming from report server

```
byte[] reportBytes = reportViewer.ServerReport.Render(
    reportType, deviceInfo, 
    out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);
```

Comment: The original contents: was it a string that you stored as binary? or are you describing binary data that you're trying to pass around as text? The question is unclear. Perhaps an example including the payload and the expected result would help.

Comment: i need to convert byte array data into datatable or list or any format and the byte array data contains excel data.@MarcGravell

Comment: again, that is ambiguous and the details *really, really matter here*. I'm concerned that you might be trying to encode *backwards*, which is pretty much a guaranteed way to corrupt your data. When you say "the byte array data contains excel data" - what does that mean? is the byte array data *actually encoded text*? if it isn't: **do not use `Encoding`. here. If it *is* text data and you're just trying to decode the `byte[]` to `string`, then fine: just use `Encoding.UTF8` and you're done.

Comment: the data is coming from report server into reportbytes 
`byte[] reportBytes = reportViewer.ServerReport.Render(reportType, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);`

Comment: i have uploaded the image of excel file which is stored as byte

Comment: k; I need to try to step back a bit here. As a file or any other transport or storage mechanism, *everything* will be bytes. The png image doesn't help, because what we need to know is: *what format are the actual bytes in*. They *could* be a text format of some kind, in which case yes, we need an `Encoding`. But you really aren't making it easy to understand how the data here is actually stored. What it *contains* is largely irrelevant - it is the storage format that is important.

Answer (score 1):

The values from 0 to 255 are bytes. The characters in your text are being represented as bytes. There are many different encodings, to convert characters into bytes and vice versa. UTF-8 is one of the most used these days. If text is encoded using UTF-8 encoding, you should also decode it using UTF-8 encoding.

So, assuming `fileBytes` is a `byte[]` containing UTF-8 encoded text:

```
string text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileBytes)
```

Comment: i need to convert byte array data into datatable or list or any format and the byte array data contains excel data

Comment: Update your question then with what you are actually trying to accomplish, and what your data looks like. It's hard to guess what you are trying to do. Your question implies the data wil be used as a string.

Answer (score 0):

If your byte array is the representation of a UTF8 string, your code is not working correctly as your are using plain ASCII encoding which handles differently those characters over a certain threshold (code points below 0x7F are in common).

You read a UTF8 string from a byte array in this way:

```
string text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

and you convert it back

```
var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
```

Comment: i need to convert byte array data into datatable or list or any format and the byte array data contains excel data

Comment: Once you read your bytes and converted into a string-based value, what do you want to with it? should it be readable by the user. if so, the code converts the string from bytes to string assuming the bytes are indeed a well formed UTF8 string.

Answer (score 0):

You might just

```
File.WriteAllBytes(reportBytes, $"My Report{fileNameExtension}");
```

and depend on the operating system's file association to be sufficient when the file is opened.

You could also use `mimeType` to interpret the bytes. If it is "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", you could process the bytes with an OpenXML API library such as the OpenXML Library or ClosedXML or EPPlus.

Or, you could render into the page with the [WebForms ReportViewer Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/using-the-webforms-reportviewer-control?view=sql-server-2017).